In medusa nextjs useToggleState() are showing error. How to solve it?
The index.tsx file in my Next.js (14.04) project has invokes a function useToggleState:
export default async function Nav() {
    const regions = await listrRegions().then((regions) => regions)
    const toggleState = useToggleState()

This line triggers an error:
Error: (0, _medusajs_ui__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.useToggleState) is not a function

This suggests that the function is either not exported from the module or not available in the current scope of the code. The error occurs on line 13 of the file src/modules/layout/templates/nav/index.tsx.
How can I solve this error?

Try adding "use client" to the top of your file.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
